# Infobright Enterprise Edition (IEE) service won't start?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, infobright

I went to www.infobright.com, downloaded Infobright Enterprise Edition (IEE), and installed it. However, the service won't start, and it gives me absolutely no hint as to what the error is and why.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve the problem. I serve as the community manager for Infobright, so ff you have any further issues with Infobright, please feel free to reach out to me or our community forums. Our forums are located at http://www.infobright.org. Cheers, Jeff Kibler
jeff@infobright.com

Comment: No problem. As an aside, it took me 2 days to solve the original problem with MySQL starting up, and about 2 hours to solve this problem. I strongly suggest you fix this bug in the installer, so that the user is not presented with (a) a non-responsive port resulting from (b) a service that won't start coupled with (c) no error message anywhere that indicates the cause of the problem. Why don't you make the user select the .lic file as part of the installation? Wouldn't that save immense amounts of frustration from thousands of future users of InfoBright, and increase your market share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infobright is just MySQL with a custom engine that implements a column based database with high compression.

Go into C:\Program Files\Infobright\bin, and type:

```
mysqld --console
```

This starts Infobright in standalone console mode (rather than in service mode). The command line parameter "--console" pipes any errors to the console (rather than swallowing the errors to a file hidden somewhere on the hard drive). You will receive something similar to the following:

```
C:\Program Files\Infobright\bin>mysqld --console

Loading configuration for Infobright instance ...
Option: AllowMySQLQueryPath, value: 1.
Option: AutoConfigure, value: 0.
Option: CacheFolder, value: C:\Program Files\Infobright\cache.
Option: ControlMessages, value: 0.
Option: InternalMessages, value: 0.
Option: KNFolder, value: BH_RSI_Repository.
Option: KNLevel, value: 99.
Option: LicenseFile, value: <unknown>.
Option: LoaderMainHeapSize, value: 400.
Option: PushDown, value: 1.
Option: ServerMainHeapSize, value: 1300.
Option: UseMySQLImportExportDefaults, value: 0.
Infobright instance configuration loaded.
101223 19:05:44 [ERROR] Error: No License file found in default path.
101223 19:05:44 [ERROR] Please place License file iblicense-*.lic in directory C:\Program Files\Infobright\/.
101223 19:05:44 [ERROR] Plugin 'BRIGHTHOUSE' init function returned error.
101223 19:05:44 [ERROR] Plugin 'BRIGHTHOUSE' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
101223 19:05:44 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported table type: brighthouse
101223 19:05:44 [ERROR] Aborting
101223 19:05:45 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

To fix this error, browse to http://support.infobright.com/Support/License_Keys/ and download a license key.

For the 64-bit version of Infobright, copy the .lic file to:

```
C:\Program Files\InfoBright
```

For the 32-bit version of Infobright, copy the .lic file to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\InfoBright
```

and you will get something like the following:

```
C:\Program Files\Infobright\bin>mysqld --console

Loading configuration for Infobright instance ...
Option: AllowMySQLQueryPath, value: 1.
Option: AutoConfigure, value: 0.
Option: CacheFolder, value: C:\Program Files\Infobright\cache.
Option: ControlMessages, value: 0.
Option: InternalMessages, value: 0.
Option: KNFolder, value: BH_RSI_Repository.
Option: KNLevel, value: 99.
Option: LicenseFile, value: <unknown>.
Option: LoaderMainHeapSize, value: 400.
Option: PushDown, value: 1.
Option: ServerMainHeapSize, value: 1300.
Option: UseMySQLImportExportDefaults, value: 0.
Infobright instance configuration loaded.
101223 19:13:05 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
101223 19:13:05 [Note] Infobright Enterprise Edition 3.4.2 is ready for connections.
socket: '' port: 5029 build number (revision)=IB_3.4.2_DPN128_r9255_11467(iee_eval - commercial)
```

At this point, we know that everything is working, so we can kill this process by pressing Ctrl-C, and start the service. It will now work.

**Update:**

The solution to this problem was taken from https://serverfault.com/questions/214435/error-1067-the-process-terminated-unexpectedly-when-trying-to-install-mysql-on